# Jquery autocomplete not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My autocomplete is not working , i have alerted the response from ajax , it is json

```
 <script src="../jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
            var arr=[];
            $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
               url:'showtags.php',
               success:function(res)
               {
                  arr = $.parseJSON( res );
                  $('#tags').autocomplete({
                     source:arr
                  });
               }
            });

        });
```

I also found out that the arr is not an array as a normal array in javascript displayed all its elements when we do alert(arr) , but it says [Object object].

the res variable is = {"1":"hello","72":"call you","73":"this is me"}

the arr variable is = object{1="hello",72="call you",73="this is me"}

Comment: try arr.push($parseJSON(res));

Comment: @johnsmith    still not working

Comment: You do know that [autocompletion](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) is a feature provided by jQuery *UI*, not the basic jQuery, right?

Comment: @n.st yup sir i know and i have added the cdn of jQuery UI

Comment: @johnSmith i tried arr.push and after that i did alert(arr[1]);,it said undefined , why?

Comment: why don't you use jQuery's `getJSON` instead of `ajax`. jQuery will parse the AJAX answer on it's own and give you an object to work with instead of a string.

Comment: console is showing perfect result as i wanted but autocomplete not working

Comment: now i get it. you need an array for autocomplete, but you are getting an object!

Comment: @lordvlad  yuuuhuuuu,now please tell me how to get it

Comment: in your php you have to make sure that you are writing an array, not an object. are you using json_encode? drop the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT option, if you have it set. otherwise, make sure that you are encoding an array and not an object in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting an `object` in your response, but you need an `array` for autocomlete to work. if you can access your backend, you have to fix it there, otherwise, you have to iterate your AJAX' return value and try to convert the object into an array.

---

Javascript doesn't understand the concept of PHPs `associative` arrays, and as JSON is JAVASCRIPT object notation, JSON doesn't understand them either. You have to make sure that your array is a simple array ( i.e. no forced array keys) when you use PHPs `json_encode`, or you will get an object in JSON instead of an array.

```
$a = array("1"=>"one", "3"=>"three");
echo json_encode($a)
// {"1":"one", "3"=>"three"}
// doesn't work for jQuery.autocomplete

$b = array(array("id"=>"1", "label"=>"one"), array("id"=>"3","label"=>"three"));
echo json_encode($b);
// [{"id":1, "label":"one"}, {"id":3, "label":"three"}]
// works for jQuery.autocomplete
```

Comment: i have echo(json_encode($array)) in my backend where $array contains the data as $array[$row["id:]]=$row["name"];

Comment: that's your problem right there, javascript doesn't work with forced keys on arrays. try to save your object in the form `array(array("id"=>$row["id"],"value"=>$row["name"]), ... )`. that way, your array is an simple array and stays an array upon JSON conversion, and not an 'associative' one, which converts to an object.

Comment: an a side note, use 'label' instead of 'value' for jquery autocomplete. makes stuff easier

Comment: i want the array to be like $arr[1]="hello" and 1 and hello will come from database, how can i do that,i am new in php

Comment: First, You should use [PDO](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fde%2Fbook.pdo.php&ei=CqlTUsjgDcSn0AW424HACQ&usg=AFQjCNEP-AEmekHFYGe-P7qXQrunNRXXNg&sig2=H6TT5bs8o3XGRnh8uQ5R_w&bvm=bv.53537100,d.d2k) to access you database. Then, you can do Smith like this:`$arr=$dbh->query("select ID, VALUE from table;")->fetchAll()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the constructor of autocomplete in the success handler of your ajax call, like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            var arr=[];
            $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
               url:'showtags.php',
               success:function(res)
               {
                  arr = $.parseJSON( res );
                  $('#tags').autocomplete({
                         source:arr
                   });
               }
            });

        });
```

The way you are doing it, the constructor will be called immediately after your request is sent (before the response arrives and your array is populated), so the autocompletion will be initialised with an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the constructor of autocomplete after the ajax call.
Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr=[];
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'showtags.php',
        success:function(res)
        {
            arr = $.parseJSON( res );
            $('#tags').autocomplete({
                source:arr
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you have to discover what you receive in 'res' variable and post here  the content of  'res' variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing call-by-value (or at least the way it is used by javascript).

Consider the following example:

```
var arr = [];
var x = {x: arr};
arr = [0,1];
console.log(x.x); // Outputs []
```

What happens here?
When you create your object `x` the reference of `arr` is passed call-by-value to the object constructor. So `x.x` is now pointing at our initial empty array.
When you now set `arr` to another value you just overwrite our reference to our initial array with the reference to new array. So `arr` is now pointing to our new array containing `[0,1]`.

You could solve this by using apply (given that res is an array).

```
arr.push.apply(arr, $.parseJSON( res ));
```

`arr` now equals to `res` (given that arr was empty before)

EDIT: As the question was edited since my answer. Here the original code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var arr=[];
        $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'showtags.php',
           success:function(res)
           {
              arr = $.parseJSON( res );
           }
        });
        $('#tags').autocomplete({
          source:arr
        });
    });
```

Comment: i am really not getting how this applies to the question.